# Is there a benefit to prepending "self." to a keypath?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, key-value-observing

I see many keypaths being specified as `self.someProperty` instead of just `someProperty`. Is there a benefit to doing this? Are the two keypaths equivalent?

Edit: I am talking about keypath strings, for example used in bindings, sent to `observeValueForKeyPath:`, or returned from `keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey:`

Comment: You are talking about property references but using the term *keypath*, which has meaning in *KVC*.  Very confusing...

Comment: If you mean you see this a lot: `[self valueForKeyPath:@"self.someProperty"]`, then I would say no, there are no advantages to that and it would even make it less readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean with `valueForKey:`/`setValue:forKey:` or just directly as per the difference between:

```
var = 8;
self.var = 8;
```

Assuming the latter, the difference is that the former stores the value directly, C style, whereas the latter calls the setter (or getter, depending on context).

Calling the method costs basically nothing to take that issue off the table but has the advantages that:

- the property is key-value observing compliant; and
- you can add whatever other processing logic you want to the set. But more than that: so can subclasses, so your class becomes a better citizen in a large project.

EDIT: if the former then, no, there are no behavioural advantages but I guess that using key-value coding on yourself is such an unusual thing to do there's a benefit it making it look unusual?

Comment: What about the default naming of instance variables?  Wouldn't the instance variable be called `_var`?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear; I am talking about `valueForKey` keypaths, where as far as I can tell, `var` and `self.var` are the same thing. Is that true?

Comment: `var` and `self.var` _might_ be the same thing. If you synthesize with `@synthesize var;` then yes, they are... but you can also `@synthesize var = _var;`, in which case `self.var` and `_var` are the same thing. Because synthesis leads to creating an instance variable, some people want to prepend the underscore it it.